# Getting people across projects

Tags: c#, .net, basecamp

I am using the BCXAPI for .net and I am trying to get a list of people for a project but this doesn't seem to be available in the API.

I found documentation that shows it's possible:

```
GET /projects/#{project_id}/people.xml
```

but I was hoping not to have to break pattern and stick with using the api.

Can someone validate my suspicion that this can't be done with the BCXAPI?

I have been trying to piece together bits and pieces from different articels and I'm trying this approach:

```
var basecampProjects = s.GetProjects(a.Id);

                foreach (var proj in basecampProjects)
                {
                    var client = new RestClient()
                    {
                        BaseUrl = new Uri("https://basecamp.com/" + a.Id + "/api/v1/projects/" + proj.Id + "/people.json/")
                    };

                    client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(AccessToken.access_token);

                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                    request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PicoDev (trevor@l9digitalstrategies.com)");
                    request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    request.AddHeader("charset", "utf - 8");
                    request.AddHeader("Authorization", AccessToken.access_token);
                    request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
                    request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
                    var result = client.Execute(request);

                    string jsonResult = result.Content;

                }
```

But I am getting a "not found" result.  Is this not available anymore or am I just making a mistake in my call?

Ok so I found out that this is possible using the BCXAPI, here is how I implemented it [api documentation here](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/accesses.md)

```
var accounts = s.GetAccounts();
        foreach (var a in accounts.accounts)
        {
            try
            {
                var basecampProjects = s.GetProjects(a.Id);
                foreach (var proj in basecampProjects)
                {
                    var accesses = s.GetAccessesForProject(a.Id, proj.Id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the Uri correct? "/people.json/" has a backslash at the end?
Based on this link https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/people.md

Comment: I removed the extra forward slash but I still get the same result.  It's like the function is no longer available.